# I thought ValueTuple was built-in to .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0, valuetuple

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 website running with a .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library DLL.  I thought I understood ValueTuple and .NET Standard 2.0.  Apparently I don't.  Here's a ValueTuple defined in a .NET Standard 2.0 DLL.

```
    public static IEnumerable<(string state, int program)> StateManufacturers
    {
        get
        {
            //blah blah, read a database and return some StateManufacturers
            return _StateManufacturers;
        }
    }
```

Here's what happens when it gets called from another file located in a 4.7.2 DLL...

```
var validStateManufacturers = ABC.Globals.StateManufacturers;
```

**Compiler Error Message**: BC30643: Property 'StateManufacturers' is of an unsupported type.

If I take that EXACT same code and move it to a .NET Framework 4.7.2 Class Library DLL, it works fine.
[According to this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.8) it should work fine in .NET Standard 2.0.
What am I missing?  MSFT is encouraging us to move to .NET Standard 2.0+, and yet stuff like this keeps happening...

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. You're showing C# code and a [VB error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30643). Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The original code was in VB.  I translated a one-liner to C# to remain consistent with prior code.  In any case, here's the original...Dim validStateManufacturers = ABC.Globals.StateManufacturers.  The puzzle remains....

Comment: To add some more context, I've built this with Microsoft.Net.Compilers (rosyln) 2.8.0.  I'm assuming that it understands ValueTuple, as I have other code outside of .NET Standard 2.0 that uses ValueTuple.

Comment: Still need a repro.

Comment: I have a hint: when I `nuget restore` and System.ValueTuple is downloaded, the package cache directory `System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0` contains an empty file called `_._`, while the other .NET directories in `\lib` contain an actual `System.ValueTuple.dll`. Perhaps the dotnet team shipped a broken build config.